# PyCharm replaces characters in docstrings

Tags: python, pycharm

In the latest version of pycharm (2016.1)
There's a strange behavior - some characters in docstrings are mapped to other characters - only in the display - any workarounds?

Example:

```
def main(self, args=None):
    """

    :param args: List of arguments, with the 'aws' removed.  For example,
        the command "aws s3 list-objects --bucket foo" will have an
        args list of ``['s3', 'list-objects', '--bucket', 'foo']``.

    """
```

looks like:

[image]

Comment: This looks like your theme font is corrupted. If you reset your profile to the default fonts and restart the IDE, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid correct - the font changed somehow during the upgrade.
Write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your font gets corrupted in your profile. Due to many complications in font rendering in Java vs the OS, there are many things than cause such artifacts to be displayed.

The easiest way to solve this is to reset the font configuration for the theme and then restart the IDE.